# How to force spaces instead of tabs regardless of major mode?

Tags: emacs

I want all tabs to be 4 spaces. I have the following in `.emacs`

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq c-basic-indent 4)
(setq tab-width 4)
```

But this gets overwritten by some of the major mode themes that I can use. Is there a way to force this issue through my `.emacs` file?

Comment: Are you sure you really want this? Some file formats (e.g. makefiles) need tabs to work properly.

Comment: You can still use `C-q TAB` to insert literal tabs then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this to overwrite whatever any major mode overwrites:

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 
          '(lambda () 
             (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
             (setq c-basic-indent 4)
             (setq tab-width 4)))
```

Note though that major modes that aren't based on `c-mode` are not likely to care about `c-basic-indent` and may potentially use their own, mode-specific indentation variables. In such cases, there's no way around configuring these variables manually.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a default [C indentation style](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Custom-C-Indent.html), rather than declaring specific style parameters.

```
(setq c-default-style "k&r2")  ;; or whatever your preference is
(set-default 'indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" this problem with a particularly ugly hack. Rather than try to figure out how to get the right major mode hooks in place, I just did the following:

```
(defun save-buffer-without-tabs ()
  (interactive)
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max))
  (save-buffer))
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-s" 'save-buffer-without-tabs)
```

This horribly breaks some things (that I care about, those things are Python and Makefiles). Thus, I also did the following:

```
;; restore the original save function for makefiles
(add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key makefile-mode-map "\C-x\C-s" 'save-buffer)))

;; restore the original save function for python files
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda () (define-key python-mode-map "\C-x\C-s" 'save-buffer)))
```

I wasn't aware of the `after-change-major-mode-hook` mentioned by Thomas, but if his solution doesn't work for you for some reason, I've been using this for a few years now without incident.

**Edit**: Upon closer inspection, I don't think you're asking exactly the question I answered. I guess nuking all the tabs is one way to get consistent indentation. :)